# Add buttons programmatically via ngOnChanges in renderer2

Tags: html, typescript, elementref

for a project I need to add buttons programmatically via `ngOnChanges` in `renderer2`. I tried it with `ElementRef` in `constructor`, as `@ViewChild` and with direct, unsafe, inserting, but there is no button showing up. I need to react on text as `@Input`, that's why I need to do it in `ngOnChanges` (if there is a working other way I will accept it). I'm working with Angular/Node 12 and TypeScript 4.

My `ngAfterViewInit()` is empty.

I worked on a tiny example project, so I can share this little code snippet:

HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div [innerHTML]="html" id="html-wrap" #htmlWrap></div>
</div>
```

`constructor`:

```js
@ViewChild('htmlWrap', { static: false })
  public htmlWrap!: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elementRef: ElementRef) {  }
    // elementRef is not used in this example
```

`ngOnChanges()`-Method:

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    for (const propName in changes) {
      // did something with text for innerHTML

      const pres = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
      if (!pres) return; 

      pres.forEach((pre: HTMLElement) => {
        const buttonWrapper = this.addButtons();
        this.renderer.appendChild(pre, buttonWrapper);
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.htmlWrap.nativeElement, pre)
      });
    }
  }
```

`addButtons()`-Method:

```js
private addButtons(): HTMLElement | null {
    const wrapper = this.renderer.createElement('div');

    if (!wrapper)
      return null;

    // create buttons via this.renderer.createElement("button");
    // same with texts

    this.renderer.appendChild(button1, text1);

    // add button event

    this.renderer.appendChild(wrapper, button);

    return wrapper;
  }
```

Edit: forgot to mention @ViewChild. Sorry.